# Property structure reorder in Octobercms

Tags: php, laravel, yaml, octobercms, octobercms-backend

I am using Octobercms/Wintercms and I identified in the documentation (https://docs.octobercms.com/2.x/backend/reorder.html#configuring-a-behavior) that there is the possibility of reordering the records of a relationship, adding only one structure option in the config_relation.yaml file, however I have already added this configuration in N ways and it does not work, it does not appear in the list of the data the drag and drop option.

Attempts I made:

```
# ===================================
#  Relation Behavior Config
# ===================================

tickets:
    label: 'cashless.events::lang.relations.tickets'
    view:
        list: $/cashless/events/models/ticket/columns.yaml
        toolbarButtons: create|delete
    manage:
        form: $/cashless/events/models/ticket/fields.yaml
        recordsPerPage: 10
    structure:   
        showTree: true       
        showReorder: true
        maxDepth: 2          
        dragRow: true
```

Attempts 2:

```
tickets:
    label: 'cashless.events::lang.relations.tickets'
    view:
        list: $/cashless/events/models/ticket/columns.yaml
        toolbarButtons: create|delete
        structure:   
            showTree: true       
            showReorder: true
            maxDepth: 2          
            dragRow: true
    manage:
        form: $/cashless/events/models/ticket/fields.yaml
        recordsPerPage: 10
```

Attempts 3

```
tickets:
    label: 'cashless.events::lang.relations.tickets'
    view:
        list: $/cashless/events/models/ticket/columns.yaml
        toolbarButtons: create|delete        
    manage:
        form: $/cashless/events/models/ticket/fields.yaml
        recordsPerPage: 10
        structure:   
            showTree: true       
            showReorder: true
            maxDepth: 2          
            dragRow: true
```

Nothing works.

Comment: Got a link to the docs where you saw this?

Comment: @zanderwar added link the docs in main post